# Trouble passing HTTPS communication through mitmproxy

Tags: python-3.x, https, proxy

I'm trying to debug a HTTPS connection using `mitmproxy` and Python 3. The idea is the following: the proxy is running locally, and I tell Python to use it for a HTTPS connection; Python must accept the self-signed certificate created by `mitmproxy` for this to work, and if all goes fine, the console of `mitmproxy` will show me the decoded request/response pair.

I am able to do what I want with Python 3 and `requests`, but I have to do it using the standard `urllib`, alas, and I'm failing. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import urllib.request
import ssl

proxy = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'https': 'localhost:8080'})
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

ssl_ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ssl_ctx.check_hostname = False
ssl_ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
#ssl_ctx = ssl._create_unverified_context()

req = urllib.request.Request('https://github.com')

with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as res:
#with urllib.request.urlopen(req, context=ssl_ctx) as res:
    print(res.read().decode('utf8'))
```

When the above code is executed, I get a
    ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)
error, which means the proxy is used, but its certificate doesn't validate. This is exactly what I expect to happen at this point.

When I use the commented out line to use the `ssl_context` (create in any of the ways), I get the contents of the page I request, but the proxy console never shows the decoded request information, it stays blank. It is as though using the `ssl_context` circumvents the proxy altogether.

Could someone please help me out and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**: just to make sure, I changed the proxy port to 8081, and now the code **not** using the `ssl_ctx` variable fails with 'connection refused' (as expected), and the code using the `ssl_ctx` works fine - this asserts my assumption that the proxy is not used at all.

Comment: So I guess it is impossible by default, the note 'Currently urllib.request does not support fetching of https locations through a proxy. However, this can be enabled by extending urllib.request as shown in the recipe [6].' in https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html#id13 says so. The recipe it leads to is for Python 2, one of the comments links to a Python 3 version, which fails with 'TypeError: do_open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'' somewhere deep in the urllib code. I won't try to make it work any longer, there is no point.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking this and posting the code you tried.  I'm not sure why the documentation claims that fetching HTTPS through a proxy is not supported, because it does work.

Instead of explicitly passing the SSL context, I created and installed an `HTTPSHandler` in addition to the `ProxyHandler`.  This worked for me (Python 3.5 + mitmproxy):

```
import urllib.request
import ssl

ssl_ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ssl_ctx.check_hostname = False
ssl_ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

ssl_handler = urllib.request.HTTPSHandler(context=ssl_ctx)
proxy_handler = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'https': 'localhost:8080'})

opener = urllib.request.build_opener(ssl_handler, proxy_handler)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    req = urllib.request.Request('https://...')

    with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as res:
        print(res.read().decode('utf8'))
```

Once this opener is installed, it's used as the default for all requests using urllib, even in third-party libraries -- which is what I needed.

I'm not sure, though, why your commented out line didn't work.  Perhaps passing the context in `urlopen` installs a new opener that overrides the custom one.